# Value "undefined" when trying to consume an API REST in c# with React Native and Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am making an Android application with the Expo framework. I am a beginner with React Native and I don't know why I get this "error".
When I try to consume the Rest API I get that the values are "undefined".
The Rest API is in C #, I don't know if it's how I made the API or it's trying to consume the API.

This would be my code in React Native with Expo:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
console.reportErrorsAsExceptions = false;
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state={
    data:{'Medicines':'Cargando...'}
  }
  
  getJsonData = () =>{
    fetch('https://localhost:5001/api/Medicines/',
    {method:'GET'}).then((response)=>response.json())
    .then((responseJson)=>{
      console.log(responseJson);
      this.setState({
        data:responseJson
      })
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
      console.error(error)
    });
  }

  componentDidMount=()=>{
    this.getJsonData();
  }
  
  render(){
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={{margin:10, fontSize:16}}>{'ID: '+ this.state.data['id']}</Text>
          <Text style={{margin:10, fontSize:16}}>{'Name: '+ this.state.data['name']}</Text>
          <Text style={{margin:10, fontSize:16}}>{'Price: '+ this.state.data['price']}</Text>
          <Text style={{margin:10, fontSize:16}}>{'Mark: '+ this.state.data['mark']}</Text>
          <Text style={{margin:10, fontSize:16}}>{'Description: '+ this.state.data['description']}</Text>
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
      );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

This is what I get when using the expo web view (I use the expo web view as the Android view consumes too much resource from my PC), for what it's worth:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define your state with a `data` **object**, later in the setState, you update it with an **array of object**.

so change your state definition:

```
state = {
  data: []
}
```

If you want to have a default value, you can initialize your `state.data`:

```
state = {
  data: [{id: 0, name: "", mark: "", description: "", ...}]
}
```

After a successful API call, your data will be:

```
state = {
  data = [
   {id: 0, name: 'Moderna', price: 0, ...},
   {id: 1, name: 'Patillas', price: 123.5, ...},
  ]
}
```

Now, in the `return` method you can loop throughout the `data` to show all the data or show the first item:

```
render(){

 console.log(this.state.data)

 const firstElement = this.state.data[0]

      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={{margin:10, fontSize:16}}>{'ID: '+ firstElement.id}</Text>
          <Text style={{margin:10, fontSize:16}}>{'Name: '+ firstElement.name}</Text>
          <Text style={{margin:10, fontSize:16}}>{'Price: '+ firstElement.price}</Text>
          <Text style={{margin:10, fontSize:16}}>{'Mark: '+ firstElement.mark}</Text>
          <Text style={{margin:10, fontSize:16}}>{'Description: '+ firstElement.description}</Text>
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
      );
    }
```

**Note:** you can put a `console.log` in the `render` method and before the `return` to see the data.

##### Update

If you want to loop throughout your data, you need to create another component (can be a functional component):

```
const ShowItem = ({id, name, price, mark, description}) => (
    <View style={styles.container} key={id}>
      <Text style={{margin:10, fontSize:16}}>{'ID: '+ id}</Text>
      <Text style={{margin:10, fontSize:16}}>{'Name: '+ name}</Text>
      <Text style={{margin:10, fontSize:16}}>{'Price: '+ price}</Text>
      <Text style={{margin:10, fontSize:16}}>{'Mark: '+ mark}</Text>
      <Text style={{margin:10, fontSize:16}}>{'Description: '+ description} </Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
)
```

**Note:** Don't forget to pass the `key`

Now, use it on the `App` component:

```
render(){
  return(
    <View>
     {
       this.state.data.map(item => (
         <ShowItem 
            id={item.id}
            name={item.name} 
            price={item.price}
            mark={item.mark}
            description={item.description}
         /> 
       ))
     }
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: I already fixed the "undefined" error, but I would not know how to create a loop to show all the stored data.

Comment: I've updated my answer right now, check it @Moya

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a array in response and you are accessing the state as an object in UI.
Change your code to this: this.state.data[0].id and similarly other fields as well.

Comment: Change the code to `<Text style = {{margin: 10, fontSize: 16}}> {'ID:' + this.state.data [0] .id} </Text>` But it gives me the following error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id'). @SuyashGaonkar

Comment: @Moya state = [],you would change the code to <Text style = {{margin: 10, fontSize: 16}}> {'ID:' + this.state.data [0] .id} </Text>.

Comment: Final changes would like this :  
state = { data: [] }
<Text style = {{margin: 10, fontSize: 16}}> {'ID:' + this.state.data[0] .id} </Text>